# SQL REQUEST, why do I get more results with my GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.ContactName 
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.CustomerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
                               FROM Orders 
                               WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Orders.OrderDate) = 1998)
```

returns 81 results.

Yet this query here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.ContactName, DATEPART(YEAR,Orders.OrderDate) 
FROM Customers, Orders
GROUP BY Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderDate
HAVING DATEPART(YEAR, Orders.OrderDate) = 1998
```

returns 91 results...

Not too sure to understand why

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And in your case - you're not providing any **join conditions**;, so essentially it's a cartesian product - each row from one table multiplied by each row of the second table ..... horribly bad.....

Comment: your second query creates a cross join between customers and orders, so obviously it will return more rows. The DISTINCT in the sub-query is useless by the way.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it

Comment: As is the `DISTINCT` in the second query as you have a `GROUP BY`; so your data is already being returned in distinct sets.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Don't use `SELECT DISTINCT`. There are situations when this is appropriate, but these situations are extremely rare. If you think you must use `SELECT DISTINCT`, then ask yourself why. Most often, it either isn't necessary at all or you have inflated the data yourself by inadequate joins. Your first `DISTINCT` in your first query may be an exception. Many customers can use the same contact  obviously and as you don't have a table for contacts (yet), you use a distinct query to get the distinct contacts. That's okay.

Comment: `IN (SELECT DISTINCT` is doing my head in. It's unnecessary, but even though the compiler would probably optimize it away, it should be avoided. And if you want to hit the index, you need `Orders.OrderDate >= '1998-01-01' AND Orders.OrderDate < '1999-01-01'`